# Nextjs 14.0.4 npm run dev shows module not found '.../favicon.ico?__next_metadata__' when running everytime

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

Every time I try to create a Next.js project with `npx create-next-app@latest`, and run it with `npm run dev`, I'm getting this `module not found` error. I can't find any file which the error is trying to point to!

[image: terminal]
[image: localhost-error-page]

I'm using a Windows 11 PC. I did a fresh installation of Node.js version `20.10.0`. My `npm` version is `10.2.5`.

I've been trying it for many times. With ESLint, without ESLint. With Typescript, without Typescript. And so on. But none resolved my issue.

I searched online and found some suggestions, such as, deleting `.next` folder, deleting `node-modules`, deleting `npm cache`. None of those helped!

How do I run a new Next.js project if this issue keeps occurring with every fresh project I try to create?